# Has used to vs. usually know

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say Stephen Curry is making a promise to himself. And it goes like this:

> ”I will be the champion in this field(NBA), greater than what everybody **has used** to know.''

Or

> "I will be the champion in this field(NBA), greater than what everybody **usually** know.''

I think the first example is correct and sounds good, but I'm not sure. Could pls.shed a light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *use to know* is not at all idiomatic. I'm not sure what that would even mean. You're probably confusing it with the expression [**used to do something**](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_used-to-do.htm) which, I don't think, is going to work here either. And it should be *everybody knows*, not *everybody know* because *everybody* is a third-person singular pronoun. Third-person singular nouns and pronouns, as you may have probably heard, have their verbs end in "s". Get your basic English grammar straight. But, personally, I would rewrite your sentence entirely:

> I will become the greatest NBA player the world has ever known.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that, it should be 'knows'. Anyway, is this grammatical now: ''I will become one of the hall of famers in NBA, and even greater than the world has ever known.'' Is it ok now?

Comment: It may be grammatically okay, but the phrasing is still a little bit awkward. How about this: *I will enter the NBA Hall of Fame as one of the greatest basketball players the world has ever seen/known.*

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I think I have already got what I needed, specifically the relative clause ''and even greater than the world has ever known.''